# Django - Admin ListFilter on QuerySet witn .extra()

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

More than one day trying to figure out on how to use the Django Admin list_filter on a QuerySet using .extra()

In the AdAdmin I need to add one new column 'ad_hist_status_id' from the model AdHist so I can use this portion of the code on SomeListFilter:

```
def queryset(self, request, queryset):
    return queryset.filter(ad_hist_status_id=self.value())
```

It looks like impossible. Doing this with sql is easy:

```
select a.*, ah.ad_hist_status_id from ad_ad a
join ad_adhist ah on ah.ad_id = a.id
where
ah.datetime_end is null
order by a.id DESC
```

Until now I cannot make to work this SomeListFilter in the Django Admin, the error is:

```
FieldError at /admin/ad/ad/

Cannot resolve keyword 'ad_hist_status_id' into field. 
Choices are: addetailscategories, address, adhist, adphotos, 
adprice, adscheduleinfo, age, comment, county, county_id, 
date_inserted, date_updated, description, district, district_id, 
email, id, lat, lng, name, parish, parish_id, schedule_type,
schedule_type_id, telephone, title, user_inserted, user_inserted_id,
user_updated, user_updated_id
```

My question is, how do I effectively add a new column to a QuerySet and then how can I query this new QuerySet with the new column?

Some portions of my code bellow

The Models:

```
class Ad(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = models.EmailField()
    district = models.ForeignKey(District)
    county = ChainedForeignKey(County, chained_field="district", chained_model_field="district", sort=True) # smart_selects app
    parish = ChainedForeignKey(Parish, chained_field="county", chained_model_field="county", sort=True) # smart_selects app
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, null=True, blank=True)
    lng = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, null=True, blank=True)
    schedule_type = models.ForeignKey(AdScheduleType)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    user_inserted = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_inserted_ad')
    date_inserted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user_updated = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_updated_ad')
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AdHist(models.Model):
    ad = models.ForeignKey(Ad)
    datetime_begin = models.DateTimeField()
    datetime_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    ad_hist_status = models.ForeignKey(AdHistStatus)
    ad_hist_change_reason = models.ForeignKey(AdHistChangeReason)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    user_inserted = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_inserted_ad_hist')
    date_inserted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user_updated = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_updated_ad_hist')
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ad.name
```

The Admin:

```
class SomeListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('Approval State')
    parameter_name = 'ad_hist_status_id'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('1', _('Approved')),
            ('4', _('Not Approved')),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        return queryset.filter(ad_hist_status_id=self.value())

class AdAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'title', 'age', 'telephone', 
                    'email', 'district', 'county', 'parish', 
                    'ad_status', 'ad_hist_change_reason', 'comment',
                    'user_inserted', 'date_inserted', 'user_updated',
                    'date_updated', 'ad_hist_status_id')

    readonly_fields = ('ad_status', 'id', 'ad_hist_change_reason',
                   'ad_hist_status_id')

    list_filter = (SomeListFilter,)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(AdAdmin,self).get_queryset(request).extra(select={'ad_hist_status_id': 'select ad_hist_status_id from ad_adhist where ad_adhist.ad_id = ad_ad.id and ad_adhist.datetime_end is null'},)
        return qs

    def ad_hist_status_id(self, inst):
        return inst.ad_hist_status_id
```

Can someone give me a clue?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you are looking for this:

```
from django.db.models import F

def queryset(self, request, queryset):
    return queryset.filter(ad_hist_status__id=F('id'))
```

The [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#f-expressions) is used to reference a field from the same model, and to refer a field from a related model, you need to use an underscore (__).

Comment: Hi Ankur. Thank for the reply. Did not work, the model Ad, does not have any key pointing to AdHist, only AdHist points to Ad. Any clues?

Comment: Did you try this. AdHist has a foreign key to Ad, that does not mean you cannot access AdHist from Ad. Please confirm after you have tried this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look to [Django field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups). Look at what the docs say:

> Basic lookups keyword arguments take the form `field__lookuptype=value`. (That’s a **double-underscore**).

You want to take the `AdHist` related object from `Ad`, which has a related `AdHistStatus`, and get its `id`.

So you should access this `id` field like:

```
def ad_hist_status_id(self, instance):
    return instance.adhist.ad_hist_status.id
```

Or you can list it directly with the *double-underscore* syntax:

```
class AdAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (..., 'adhist__ad_hist_status__id')
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. It does not work, gives me the same error. If you see the model Ad, does not have any key pointing to AdHist, only AdHist points to Ad. Any mores clues?

Comment: @André I think I've now noticed the issue here. Your `AdHist` model has a foreign key relation to your `Ad`. This is means **"One `Ad` has many `AdHist`s"**. So you have a list of `AdHist` entries in your `Ad` instance, which you can access by `ad.adhist_set`. Think about if you want to have a `OneToOne` relationship, instead of a `ForeignKey` one.

Comment: Hi wencakisa. The OneToOne will not work because the AdHist will have more than one key reference to Ad. Any more clues?

Comment: @Adré Then your logic is a bit wrong here. You want to display a **certain** `AdHistStatus` id, but there are many `AdHist` entries in your `Ad` model. So you can't do that. You can try to use an `Inline` model admin.

Comment: The model AdHist is to track all modifications to an Ad. This method is used widely used, but I understand that Django has is own ways. I think i will create a CurrentHist model to make a OneToOne relation. Thanks